# Can I use an R library embedded in Scala with rscala?

Tags: r, scala

I imported the **org.ddahl.rscala** class into my Scala project and have gotten the minimal example found here: https://dahl.byu.edu/software/rscala/scaladoc/org/ddahl/rscala/RClient.html to run. Now I would like to use an R library embedded in my Scala code if possible; however I cannot find what syntax I would use to import an external library from the rscala package.

Calling from RClient object is not supported, the below does not work:

```
val R = org.ddahl.rscala.RClient()
R.library("libraryname")
```

Is this something which is possible to do, or is rscala limited in scope to the methods listed on the scaladocs page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
R.eval("require {library_name}")
```